# awaiting inside an awaitable function in .net

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a function that returns a Task

```
    class Sample
    {
       TaskCompletionSource<int> _tcs;
    ..
       public Task<int> DoIt(){
         StartDoingStuff();
         return _tcs.Task;
       }
      ..
    
      private void FinshedStuffCallBack(){
        _tsc.SetResult(42);
      }
    }
```

Caller goes

```
 var sample = new Sample();
  var result = await Sample.DoIt();
```

works fine

Now I need to do something in addition in DoIt, this is itself awaitable

I naively tried

```
       public async Task<int> DoIt(){
        
         await DoOtherAsyncStuff();
          StartDoingStuff();
         return _tcs.Task;
       }
```

but this is not allowed

> CS4016    Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of
> type 'int' rather than 'Task'

OK I get what its trying to say, but thats not my intention, I dont have the return value yet, it comes once StartDoingStuff triggers the callback.

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: The goal of your code isn't immediately clear to me, but you probably want `return await _tcs.Task`

Comment: I trust you understand that `..` doesn't compile, so I'm guessing that this isn't your real code. We really love to get a [mcve] to be able to help properly..

Comment: @StevenFontanella the goal is that StarDoingStuff() cannot run until DoOtherAsyncStuff has completed. StartDoingStuff launches something that will complete at some point in the future - it invokes FinishedStuffCallback when its done. The Caller of DoIt nedds to wait till StartDoingStuff is done and to get the result from that completion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you just need (note the `await` on the last line):

```cs
       public async Task<int> DoIt()
       {
           await DoOtherAsyncStuff();
           StartDoingStuff();
           return await _tcs.Task;
       }
```

`await` is needed on the last line because an `async` function returning `Task<int>` needs to return `int`, while `_tcs.Task` is a `Task<int>`. Using `await` will wait for the Task's completion and return the `int` which is what we need.

However, depending on your complete code you may want something else. For example if you're doing more complicated things with `TaskCompletionSource` you may need to remove `async` for this definition and do something like

```cs
       public Task<int> DoIt()
       {
           return DoOtherAsyncStuff().ContinueWith(_ => 
               {
                   StartDoingStuff();
                   return _tcs.Task;
               }, TaskCompletionOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
       }
```

In general it's best not to mess with TaskCompletionSource unless you're doing something more advanced, for example providing an async abstraction of something synchronous/callback based. Hence a complete code example may change my answer (for example what's the body of `StartDoingStuff` + `DoOtherAsyncStuff`?).

Comment: That worked - ty. I would never have guessed at it though. How do I signal that the Task object I return is now complete and set its result if I dont use TaskCompleteionSource. MS docs are very poor on how to create real awaitables (ie ones that wait for a later event callback)

Comment: TaskCompletionSource is the right way to do that, but your design here seems fragile; it seems like a lot of things need to happen in the correct order for a deadlock not to happen. Also, if `StartDoingStuff` is synchronous, why does it have a callback? If it's doing the work in the background, then it should probably be async and use `Task.Run`. If it's synchronous and runs on the same thread, then we can eliminate the TaskCompletionSource entirely and make it a normal function call, since all the work associated with it is synchronous anyway in that case.

Comment: StartDoingstuff starts an audio listener that waits until it hears a specific set of notes played or a timeout occurs . That listener then calls the callback indicating what it heard. The DoOtherAsync stuff is rendering some UI that the listener uses to display progress  (all of this is Blazor WASM)